# Android: Change default keyboard mode

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I am currently trying to figure out how to programmatically change the default keyboard more from floating to docked for my alertdialog editText. Is this possible? Currently when someone clicks on the edit text it pops up with a number pad but it is in the floating mode and not docked.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.  First, the keyboard is replaceable.  There is no promise that any given keyboard app uses a particular mode.  In fact, modes are something that are made up by the keyboards- the idea of keyboard modes come from the individual keyboards, not Android.  As such while its possible individual keyboards offer an API to set them, there is no common one.